# In 20.04, with a picture cropped not to 16:9 but another ratio, I click on "Add Picture..." and select it, but it doesn't do anything, no confirm even

Tags: desktop-background

I am using 20.04 and trying to add a non-16:9 wallpaper to my 16:9 monitor. I thought maybe I could center or stretch it like you can on Windows but apparently not? It's a TIFF file btw, does that matter? What are acceptable image files for wallpapers? Most of the top Google hits for this sort of thing are absolute garbage explanations that just want to boost their website traffic to make a living. Parasites.

Anyway. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Why not just grab some images you like; and adjust them to the *unstated* dimensions of your screen?

Comment: You should edit the title of your post to something shorter and to the point.  Maybe "Help with formatting a wallpaper" or something.  No one will take that title seriously.  Then, you should mention what programs you're using.  Unlike Windows, Ubuntu offers many graphic programs and any one of them can set a wallpaper.  Perhaps if you start from here, someone can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

Install Tweaks from the software center. On the "Appearance" tab, change the setting "Adjustment" listed under "Background" to your liking.